# Firebase Auth: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: javascript, firebase, cors, firebase-authentication

I have had this problem for day about cors and i could not solve it. I am using js and firebase to authenticate a user but this error keeps poping up

Any help please

[image]

Comment: Can you copy as cURL the request that is failing? That is a good way to help replicate this.

Comment: the url is from file:///C:

Comment: In the chrome browser console, right click on the failing request and then select copy -> copy as cURL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by not using the url staring with file:///C. So i will work by using xampp so that you can run your files using localhost or a url that starts with http:// or https://